# Using javascript hide 'td' having same color and background-color

Tags: javascript

```
 <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="color: aliceblue;background-color: aqua;">Y</td>
                <td style="color:green;background-color: green;">Q</td>
                <td style="color: greenyellow;background-color: lawngreen;">A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="color: blue;background-color: violet;">T</td>
                <td style="color: khaki;background-color: khaki;">P</td>
                <td style="color: aquamarine;background-color: darkblue;">D</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

We have to hide "td" having same color and background-color.

How can we do that?

We also do not have any "id" or "class" mentioned.

Can we do using getElementByTagName?

Comment: You'll need some code to start with. Do you have an attempt?

Comment: Would you like to hide `td` in the same row? or `td` in the different row?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Would like to hide middle "td" in both the "tr" as they have same color and background-color. Hide 'Q' and 'P'

Comment: So, you want to hide every middle `td` of every `tr` if they have same color and background color? Isn't it?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Not specifically middle "td". I have to hide only on the condition if "td" have same color and background-color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple `for...loop`:

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table td')

for (i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
  if (rows[i].style.color === rows[i].style.backgroundColor)
    rows[i].style.display = "none";
}

console.log(rows)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: aliceblue;background-color: aqua;">Y</td>
      <td style="color:green;background-color: green;">Q</td>
      <td style="color: greenyellow;background-color: lawngreen;">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: blue;background-color: violet;">T</td>
      <td style="color: khaki;background-color: khaki;">P</td>
      <td style="color: aquamarine;background-color: darkblue;">D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line will select all td

```
const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td')); // Converting to Array from NodeList for better browser support
```

```
tds.forEach( (elem) => {
    if(elem.style["color"] == elem.style["background-color"])
        elem.style["display"] = 'none';
})
```

This line will hide matching elements by setting display property to none

Comment: It seems `forEach` on `NodeList`s  is not widely [supported by browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. What about converting it to an array using Array.from() and then using forEach, it got 96.21%  support

Comment: I see 93.37% global support for `Array.from` on canIuse, but yes it's could be a better choice than `forEach` on `NodeList`.